# host angular app under a path - assets fail to load

Tags: angular

Angular 4 app, using ng cli.

I `ng build --prod` and host the files under a path, so instead of 'http://myserver.com/' its 'http://myserver.com/dir' (this is a mandatory requirement).

adding `--base-href "/dir/"` fixed initial loading so the app now loads and functions, but still 'assets' are not loaded because they are searched for under the root url.
I tried `--deploy-url` which didn't help either.

There are many GH issues and SO questions on this topic but I still couldn't find a clear answer.

Comment: Are your asset paths root-relative? If so, they would need to begin with `/app/assets`

Comment: it's `/assets/`. do I need the `app` part?

Comment: If you're working with the standard CLI-generated `src` directory layout, then `assets` is not inside the `app` directory - it's at the same level. You'll need to move `assets` under `app` if that's the base.

Comment: Have you tried using a relative base href? `./` ?

Comment: @Brandon when I used 'app' in the path I meant my arbitrary path name, not Angular's app directory. I have updated the question to clarify this. I did try ./ for base href, but isn't --base-href suppose to override this anyway?

Comment: I believe the `--base-href` is only for the typeScript/JS transpiled code, not for static assets like images, css, etc. If memory serves, those depend on the `<base>` tag.

Comment: I recently had to deploy an Angular (4) site to a non-root URL, and what I had to do was specify an absolute URL for the base href value. You might also give that a try.

Comment: @Brandon thanks for your comments! if by 'absolute url' you meant including hostname\dns in the html source - thats out of the question... that app is to be deployed multiple times for different tenants... There must be a better way..?

Comment: The base href value can be written dynamically.

Comment: you mean at build time or run time? is that a best practice?

Comment: You can do either. We set ours at build time, but we're only deploying to one domain.